# How to restrict shortest path - dijkstra algorithm with maximum cost?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I am wondering how I can assign a maximum cost value for the shortest path problem. In my problem, I have risks associated with nodes. So I would like to minimize risk, but while doind that I want it to find a solution with limited number of nodes.(eg. find minimum risk from node A to node B, while ensuring solution does not exceed n number of nodes) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Dijkstra is Best First Search, i.e. we should be sure, that distance to the best node never will become better. It works for minimum-Dijkstra with non-negative edges. In general case you can use [Ford-Bellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm). In case you want to use not more than n vertexes, i can suggest you Dynamic programming dp[vertex][used_vertex_count] with complexity O(|V| * n) states and memory and O(|E| * n) time. Or create adjacency matrix of the graph with zeros on main diagonal and infinity insted of absent edge and calc it's n exponent. a_{ij} will be min path from i to j using no more than n vertexes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that some algorithm that involves heuristics would be best suited here, the heuristic being a notion of how "close" to the goal you are at each step, and which node will take you closer to the goal. Without that, I think we would need to run an exponential algorithm in the worst case (which would be when the goal cannot be reached using just `n` nodes. In this case, we will look at all paths that use `n` nodes before we conclude that the problem cannot be solved).

One example of using a non-heuristic algorithm is this: Run Dijkstra's in a regular fashion selecting the node with min risk. Along the way, keep track of the number of nodes you have visited. If the number of nodes goes beyond `n` then abandon your current route and backtrack to a previous node and use the node with the next lowest risk. Naturally, you can't backtrack just one level above `n`, since if the goal were in the next level, it would have been picked. Therefore, you backtrack to level `n-2` and carry on. This too will be exponential as there isn't a real way to determine non-existence without checking all paths.

It could also be that I'm missing something.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use Prim's algorithm because it finds all minimal spanning tree in the given graph. Then it is easy to select the mst with the desired constraint.